# An easy way to limit nested matches from querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, queryselector

```
<div>
    <div>
        ...
            <div>
                <div>
                    This is some text
                    <div>The quick brown</div>
                    fox jumped
                    <div>over the</div>
                    lazy dog.
                </div>
            </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

(Note: `div` used for simplicity; could be many different element types.)

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"), el => /quick\s+brown/.test(el.innerText))
```

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"), el => /the\s+lazy\s+dog/.test(el.innerText))
```

Both queries match to multiple elements, but in each case, I'd like only one. Specifically, I'm only interested in the div that matches the regex, but does not have a child that matches the regex. In other words, the least nested match.

Is there anything that can be put into the selector that even resembles eliminating nested matches?

If not, what's an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I've discovered Node.contains(), which makes this possible:

```
var els=
    Array.prototype.filter.call(
        document.querySelectorAll("div"), el => /the\s+lazy\s+dog/.test(el.innerText)
    );

var e= 0;

while (e < els.length - 1)
    if (els[e].contains(els[e + 1]))
        els.splice(e, 1);
    else
        e++;

console.log(els);
```

(Assuming the matches are in order of parent to child, and also that we don't want any nodes that contain others that match, even if that ancestor node has another match in its own text.)

```
<div>
    " This is some text "
    <div>The quick brown</div>
    " fox jumped "
    <div>over the</div>
    " lazy dog. "
</div>
```

I'm still hoping, maybe naively, that there's a way to exclude nested matches within the selector...